# How can I upload multiple files to Amazon S3 asynchronously using the AWS SDK for .NET?

Tags: .net, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload multiple files asynchronously on Amazon S3 using the .NET SDK. Any examples to get me started will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) and [AWS SDK for .NET](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/) functionality you are looking for is [Using the High-Level .NET API for Multipart Upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/usingHLmpuDotNet.html):

> The AWS SDK for .NET exposes a high-level API that simplifies
>   multipart upload (see [Uploading Objects Using Multipart Upload API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html)).
>   **You can upload data from a** file, **directory**, or a stream. [...]
>   **You can optionally set advanced options such as the** part size you want
>   to use for the multipart upload, **number of threads you want to use
>   when uploading the parts concurrently**, optional file metadata, the
>   storage class (STANDARD or REDUCED_REDUNDANCY), or ACL. The high-level
>   API provides the `TransferUtilityUploadRequest` class to set these
>   advanced options. *[emphasis mine]*

An example snippet is provided in [Upload a Directory](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadDirDotNet.html):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Transfer;

namespace s3.amazon.com.docsamples
{
    class UploadDirectoryMPUHighLevelAPI
    {
        static string existingBucketName = "*** Provide bucket name ***";
        static string directoryPath      = "*** Provide directory name ***";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                TransferUtility directoryTransferUtility =
                    new TransferUtility(new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1));

                // 1. Upload a directory.
                directoryTransferUtility.UploadDirectory(directoryPath,
                                                         existingBucketName);
                Console.WriteLine("Upload statement 1 completed");

                // 2. Upload only the .txt files from a directory. 
                //    Also, search recursively. 
                directoryTransferUtility.UploadDirectory(
                                               directoryPath,
                                               existingBucketName,
                                               "*.txt",
                                               SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                Console.WriteLine("Upload statement 2 completed");

                // 3. Same as 2 and some optional configuration 
                //    Search recursively for .txt files to upload).
                TransferUtilityUploadDirectoryRequest request =
                    new TransferUtilityUploadDirectoryRequest
                    {
                        BucketName = existingBucketName,
                        Directory = directoryPath,
                        SearchOption = SearchOption.AllDirectories,
                        SearchPattern = "*.txt"
                    };

                directoryTransferUtility.UploadDirectory(request);
                Console.WriteLine("Upload statement 3 completed");
            }

            catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message, e.InnerException);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not at all the correct answer as this will upload all the files of the selected directory but question is how to upload multiple selected files.

Comment: You could do a workaround and rename your desired selected files by appending a common tag in the end. Then use the the SearchPattern as `"*-YourTag.txt"`

Comment: Is there a way to use multiple types of file extensions in the "SearchPattern"?